# Per-project source code providers in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

Can I use multiple source control providers at the same time in Visual Studio? Global switch is not enough for my needs (I have one project in SVN, another one in TFS etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS source control providers are per solution (each VS instance can use its SCP), not per project it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.  You probably don't want to use multiple source code tools in the same solution (that just seems confusing), but it is possible for two systems to co-exist.

I'm a little less certain whether you can multiple source control *plugins* at the same time.  For example, Visual Source Safe, TFS, and Ankh (I've never tried Visual Studio with any of those combinations).  I'm currently working with both Visual Source Safe and Subversion, but while VSS functions specifically as a source control provider, VisualSVN which shows up as a more general add-on.

**EDIT:**  Based on the back and forth in the comments.

Can multiple SCCM tools co-exist in Visual Studio as side-by-side installations?  Yes.

Can they be used in the same solution?  I've never tried it.

Comment: "Yes, it can be done" - how then? I'm asking about source control providers, not generic plugins as VisualSVN (many VCS system don't have such plugins, it's more common to have corresponding source control provider).

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you're asking.

Can Visual Studio be integrated with multiple SCCM tools at the same time?  Yes.  I'm using VSS along with VisualSVN.

By "provider", do you mean a standalone "SCCM tool?" Can Visual Studio work with a solution using multiple (non-integrated) SCCM tools?  Yes.  VSS Explorer, TortoiseSVN, SVN command line, these all work, Visual Studio need never know about the SCCM tools.

Or by "provider" do you mean a plug-in which appears under File | Source Control?  VSS, TFS and (I believe) Ankh (SVN) work that way, but I don't recall trying them together.

Comment: "but I don't recall trying them together" - I believe they can't work at once in one solution so the answer to the original question is probably "no". But thanks for the explanation anyway.

Comment: The thread author had a simple question: how to configure the Source Control Provider per Solution instead of globally. Not how to use multiple providers in a single solution.

Comment: Oliver, look at the question title :)