# How to configure Visual Studio to use different source control providers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

I'm involved in many projects and each project has their own source control provider. Is there a way to configure Visual Studio 2010 to automatically select the right source control on a per project basis? Or is the Tools - Options - Source Control plug in per user level?

Let me clarify what is happening. I have a project using Vault. When I open it VS sets the Source Control to Vault. I then close the project (solution) and open another solution that uses Mercurial (VisualHG) I check the Source Control plugin and Vault is still selected. Why? Is it possible to automatically select the right source control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Perforce and SourceSafe co-exist in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470134/can-perforce-and-sourcesafe-co-exist-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. My question is not about coexisting, but about having VS set up the source control on a per project basis.

Comment: another related answer, for the sake of completeness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921233/per-project-source-code-providers-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to automatically load a proper source control provider the solution file must contain Scc bindings.

I don't know if VisualHG supports them or not.

But you can try HgSccPackage - another mercurial plugin for MS Visual Studio 2008/2010 which supports Scc bindings.

You can get it here: http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html

If you want to add Scc bindings to an existing controlled solution, use Mercurial -> Change SCC bindings menu from the IDE. (This menu will be available when the HgSccPackage is active and you have loaded a controlled solution).

For new projects HgSccPackage automatically adds Scc bindings. It is configurable via options though, for thouse who don't like this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470134/can-perforce-and-sourcesafe-co-exist-in-visual-studio).  It appears the answer is no, you have to select the correct provider for the project before working with the project, because only one source control provider can be active at a time.

Comment: that is my question, I want for VS to automatically select the provider based on the project. I only work with one project at a time. It appears as if now it selects the last used.

Answer (score 1):

There's an additional VS plugin called [Scc Auto Switcher](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d99d30fb-3dbc-45f0-8c91-8c103e11f996?SRC=VSIDE) that can help automatically switch between SCM systems used by different projects, although the docs don't specifically mention Vault.

Answer (score 0):

Now we have 2023, and VS still supports only one SourceControl provider at a time.
If you are looking for a solution that supports SVN and GIT and you use Tortoise SVN you can handle it like I do:

1. Set the options to the "GIT" Plugin. Projects with GIT will work
2. Install the extension "TSVN 2022", it will provider a layer to the installed TSVN-Tools from VS.

This way I can work with Projects in both systems without a need to change the options everytime.