# Per-Project Source Control Providers for Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, visual-studio-2012

I have searched here, GooBingHooVista'd the world and read this related question for VS 2010: [How to configure Visual Studio to use different source control providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994009/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-diferent-source-control-providers) and the others linked. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6789773/492 is the most interesting so far, although the functionality seems to be based on a bug in VS. I would work for me although I'd rather it get it working properly.

I'm asking basically the same question fro VS 2012 - has the provider model changed &/or is it possible to have the VS integration switch source-control (SEO: version control) providers per project, rather than just per-solution?

Reason for asking: I have a projects in Hg & in Git. Git seems to be winning favour these days but presently Kiln (Fogbugz's linked repo) is Hg-only and most of my repos are there. I find it handy to be able to commit from VS with a couple of keystrokes (I set ctrl-alt-shift-C to File => Commit) rather than context-switching my feeble mind away from VS to do my housekeeping.

I'd be more than happy if needed to add an extension to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. source Control Bindings in the project files as explained at https://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/issue/78/not-modify-the-project-files-after-adding

Git Extension at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c

Hg Extension at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9bc074fa-9e1f-4ce2-a75d-b90e65f7475a