# How to switch to TFS automatically when solution is loaded?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have an annoying problem with source control plugins... I'm using VS2012 and I have some projects on TFS and others on SVN (using AnkhSVN).

When I open a SVN solution, VS seamlessly switches to AnkhSVN as the source control plugin, which is fine. But then, when I open a TFS solution, it doesn't switch back to TFS... the most annoying effect is that automatic checkout doesn't work. To fix it, I have to unload the solution, changes the source control plugin to TFS, and reload the solution.

Is this a known problem? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a good option that I can think of. That part of Visual Studio is designed to work only with one Source Control system at a time and I understand your pain.

I guess my first question is why you need both, but I guess there is some need somewhere. You can see folks with the same problem:

- [How to quickly switch source control providers in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678239/how-to-quickly-switch-source-control-providers-in-visual-studio-2010)

**Option 1: Virtualisation**

As I have a machine capable of running VM's (Windows 8 with Hyper-V) I would have two VM's with one configured for TFS and the other configured for SVN. Not elegant, but it would allow you to switch.

**Option 2: Regedit**

You can change the setting in the registry.

[HOW TO: Change Source Control Providers If Two or More MSSCCI-Compliant Providers Are Installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319318)

So you could have a "key" file for each setting stored on your desktop and:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Run registery key
3. Open Solution

While ugly and requires remembering it would be the best option locally.

**Conclusion**

There is no good answer but I do think that the two options above will get you there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately a VM is not a viable option for me. As for the registry option, I don't know what I need to change exactly...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque the second link was broken :( I have fixed it

Comment: +1: I this question on microsoft connect a long time ago.  They answered by saying that switching between source control providers based on project that is loaded isn't something they are going to do.

Comment: @ChrisLively, do you have the reference of the Connect issue?

Comment: @MrHinsh, I'm afraid the link is outdated... it applies to VS2002. The registry keys mentioned on this page don't exist.

Comment: I use VS2010 for svn, and VS2012 for tfs.