# Visual Studio - Detect Source Control Provider

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I'm using VS2010. The projects that I'm working on use different source control providers, TFS, Mercurial or SVN. Is there a way in which I can configure VS to start with a specific source control provider selected, depending on the solution which I'm loading?

For example, if VS would allow me to specify as a startup argument the source control provider it should select, I could create a launcher for each particular solution.

A more elegant solution would be for VS to scan the solution's folder for specific files (for ex. .hg for Mercurial projects) and automatically select the provider, but I'm not sure if this is possible. If someone can point me in the right direction with this approach, I would deffinetly try to write a VS plugin which would do this.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994009/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-diferent-source-control-providers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994009/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-diferent-source-control-providers as suggested by one of our users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a lot of digging on this and the only solution that I've found until now is to create my own solution.

Initially I didn't intend to make this project publicly available, but just in case anyone else would find some use in this, here's the link to the project:
https://scs.codeplex.com/

Any contributions would be greatly appreciated.